# How to access controls in Button.Content in code-behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, controls

In XAML I've created a Button like this:

```
<Button MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter">
    <Button.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="asd"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="xxx"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="2" Content="yyy"/>
        </Grid>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

And now I need to access one of those controls inside of Button's Content in code-behind. Lets say i need the TextBlock one.

```
private void Button_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = (Button)sender;
        // ? 
    }
```

How can I do that?
Also I have multiple buttons like this one created automatically with data binding. 
The reason I need to access those controls is that I want to animate one of them in certain situation.

Comment: Have tried to use Triggers in XAML directly, in order to animate your button?

Comment: Your button.Content should be a Grid, right? you can cast it.

Comment: My animation needs lots of calculations and i don't want to create too much converters for this. 

  @LuisFilipe: That did the trick :) Simple as that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **button.Content** should be a **Grid**, right? you can **cast** it.

Answer (score 3):

```
        private void Button_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = sender as Button;
        TextBox textBox = null;
        if (b != null)
        {
            foreach (var frameworkElement in ((Grid)b.Content).Children)
            {
                if (frameworkElement is TextBox)
                {
                    textBox = (TextBox)frameworkElement;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

This is just to give the idea how you can extract the child of Grid that is your button's Content. I hope this will help you to get the idea.

Comment: Great answer! Can you tell me whether it is possible to programmatically insert the contents of a button inside the  `<Button.Content>` (in this case, the entire `Grid` element) tag into another button I created programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change such things, i would suggest to use MVVM pattern and DataBinding!

=> Create a property for the text and bind the textbox to this text, than you just have to change this property and the button will change its text. See PropertyChanged-Event for MVVM!